# URL redirect with SAML enabled

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, redirect

We are planning to use SSO with SAML.  This means, as far am I am aware, that the URL being displayed in the browser will not have the format na1.salesforce.com, but the format of the sub domain being used e.g myapp.salesforce.com.  Now if you give a URL like na1.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPage, and you are not logged in, you are first prompted to log in, then automatically redirected to the page corresponding to the URL.  My question is this: does the same thing happen when you are using SAML, and you specify a URL like myapp.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPage?  I would imagine it would, but am not in a position yet to test this (we have a big internal backlog for SAML management requests), and so would like to know if someone can confirm this one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It sounds like you're talking about the [My Domain](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/domain_name_overview.htm) feature - this gives you a URL of the form `mycompany.my.salesforce.com` (almost the same as you have there, but note the `.my.` in the middle). When you hit a 'deep link' with a My Domain URL, such as `mycompany.my.salesforce.com/apex/myVFPage`, the custom hostname is recognized, you are redirected for SAML SSO (if necessary), then taken back to the requested page.

Comment: You're welcome, @hamayoun, but the way this site works is you upvote my answer, and accept it, if it answered your question :-)